# the menu of wordpress's admin page is empty

Tags: wordpress

i installed wordpress 5.1.1 with xamp and the menu of the admin page is blank.There is only the profile button...

see the picture : https://ibb.co/GkDPYwG

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Might be, you have level_0 or Subscriber user role. Kindly check the user role of the logged one.